# StereoReconstruction from Images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, stereo-3d

Is it possible to get some good reconstructed surfaces from bumbleebee cameras (produced by Point Gray Research).Does any one has any information regarding this?I am looking for a fairly simple solution which should be easy to implement.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you want to implement. In addition: do you want to extract full 3D information from a scene or is a depth map (the distance from the camera to the object) enough?

Comment: I want to eventually get the surface....however i believe if i can get the 3d points then I can find out the normals and together put both of these in poisson reconstruction to get the output surface ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked with the BumbleBee camera before. I can tell you that the built-in stereo depth software can be very sensitive to color/material properties and thus confuse shading with shape etc. Thus, reconstruction from 1 shot is likely not feasible.

If you're willing to move the camera around to do structure from motion, then try any number of SfM software such as [Bundler](http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/bundler/) and [Voodoo tracker](http://www.digilab.uni-hannover.de/docs/manual.html). These can produce a 3D point cloud.

Once you get the 3D point cloud, you can then use a 3D texture mapping software like [CMVS](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/software/cmvs/) to color the point cloud. Note that CMVS is meant to work with Bundler. You'll have to do some format conversion if you use another SfM package.

If you prefer to roll your own, I'd suggest reading the [Hartley and Zisserman classic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521540518).

Comment: Thanks pxu for the answer .Well i use FLYCAPTURE_BUMBLEBEEXB3 to be precise and it has 2 cameras( actually 3) but I use the leaft and right to find image and then it also has a kind of sample program to generate point cloud.Was wondering why didnt ppl use that? Have you tried it before?

Comment: That's what I meant by the built-in stereo depth software. It's able to handle light matte surfaces well but can become confused by more complicated things. For example, it can do stereo reconstruction of a chair well but not when a person sits in the chair.

Comment: @pxu- have you used the triclopsRCD16ToXYZ function? What i get as the output is projected on a sphere whereas I need a true 3d cloud of the object(where certain parts are clearly behind the others).I normalize the x,y,z co-ordinates before writing them out though.

Comment: I haven't used that function specifically. I was just using their packaged software to visualize the 3D structure. As for the output projected on a sphere, could that be due to your normalization?